# visual studio 2017 safemode

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2017

After I installed an extension to Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, VS crashes on startup. In previous versions there was a /safemode switch. I tried it but it seems to be no longer supported. What can I do to suppress loading of extensions in Visual Studio when it crashes (cannot disable extensions via extension manager).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is still a /SafeMode switch.  If this does not help you need to do a repair on visual studio 2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for your advice. No as I repaired/reinstalled VS, I can see the /safemode switch :).